# Javascript Add and Edit function

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects, dom-events

I have two questions. After I submit (adding) the product information, I want to make the input field blank. And the second question is to make the edit function work. It doesn't work. I have no idea on how to this. Hope you can help.

```js
var qtyTotal = 0;
    var priceTotal = 0;

    function addProduct() {
        var productID = document.getElementById("productID").value;
        var product_desc = document.getElementById("product_desc").value;
        var qty = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
        // qtyTotal = qtyTotal + parseInt(qty);
        //document.getElementById("qtyTotals").innerHTML=qtyTotal;
        var price = document.getElementById("price").value;    
        //priceTotal = priceTotal + parseInt(price);
        //document.getElementById("priceTotals").innerHTML=priceTotal;
        var table=document.getElementById("results");
        var row=table.insertRow(-1);
        var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
        var cell5=row.insertCell(4);
        var cell6=row.insertCell(5);
        cell1.innerHTML=productID;
        cell2.innerHTML=product_desc;
        cell3.innerHTML=qty;        
        cell4.innerHTML=price;  
        cell5.innerHTML=' <button type="button" onClick="editProduct();"/>Edit</button>'; 
        cell6.innerHTML ='<button type="button" onClick="deleteProduct(this);">Delete</button>';             
}

    function editProduct(){
        

        document.getElementById("productID").value = productID;
        document.getElementById("product_desc").value = product_desc;
        document.getElementById("quantity").value = qty;
        document.getElementById("price").value = price;      
 }
    function deleteProduct(node){    
    r=node.parentNode.parentNode;
    r.parentNode.removeChild(r);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shopping Cart Pure Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="order" id="order">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="productID">Product ID:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="productID" name="product" type="text" size="28" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="product">Product Desc:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="product_desc" name="product" type="text" size="28" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="quantity" name="quantity" width="196px" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="price">Price:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="price" name="price" size="28" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="reset" name="reset" id="resetbtn" class="resetbtn" value="Reset" />
    <input type="button" onclick="addProduct();" value="Add New Product" >
</form>
<br>

<table id="results">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col" width="50">Product ID</th>
        <th scope="col" width="100">Product Description</th>
        <th scope="col" width="50">Quantity</th>
        <th scope="col" width="50">Price</th>
        <th scope="col" width="50">Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<!--<table id="resultTotals" width="360">
<tr>
    <td scope="col" width="120">Totals</td>
    <td scope="col" width="120"><div id="qtyTotals"></div></td>
    <td scope="col" width="120"><div id="priceTotals"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>*/-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for the reset after adding. You just need to add a code that clicks the reset button after you add the data. `document.getElementById("resetbtn").click()` at the bottom of your `addProduct()` function.

Comment: Thank you so much it works Jalil

Comment: Your problem with regards to edit is not clear to me. Can you explain it further in your question.

Comment: I just need to make the edit function works, Jalil

Comment: Yeah, but if you push the edit button. Where do you want to get the data? Your feature needs to be clear. Do you want the user to edit through the add form or create an editable <td>

Comment: Yes. i want to edit it through the add form and replace the "add new product" button to "save" button after editing. Thanks Jalil

Comment: You can start from finding a way to get the values of the row you want to edit and copy its value to your input form. Read about parent - children - siblings relationship for DOM.

Comment: can you help me with that sir? i'm  trying that one but still i can't get it though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass parameters into your "editProduct" function to make it works.

```
cell5.innerHTML=' <button type="button" onClick="editProduct(\''+productID+'\', \''+product_desc+'\', \''+qty+'\', \''+price+'\');"/>Edit</button>'; 

function editProduct(productID, product_desc, qty, price){
    document.getElementById("productID").value = productID;
    document.getElementById("product_desc").value = product_desc;
    document.getElementById("quantity").value = qty;
    document.getElementById("price").value = price;      
 }
```

Then you need to be carefully if some inputs are empty, put some default values by example :

```
var productID = document.getElementById("productID").value || "none";
var qty = document.getElementById("quantity").value || 0;
```

Is that ok for you ?

Comment: when i click the edit button, it automatically fills out the input form when it is only numbers, but doesn't fills out the form when it has text

Comment: For strings, you need to add some quote \'. I update the code.

Comment: @vanessa how would it work if the form was on a different page from the saved data and the edit button. so that clicking on the edit button navigates you to the form and fills the form with the data to be edited

Answer (score 0):

### Edit Cells

Toggle the `["contenteditable"]` attribute from/to `true`/`false` on the first 4 `<td>` of the `<tr>` that contains the edit button that the user clicked.

### Clear `<input>`s

Simply change the button's `[type]` attribute from `"button"` to `"reset"`.

**Details are commented in example**

```js
let qtyTotal = 0;
let priceTotal = 0;

// References all <input> in <form>
const fc = document.forms.order.elements;

function addProduct() {
  const productID = fc.productID.value;
  const product_desc = fc.product_desc.value;
  const qty = fc.quantity.value;
  const price = fc.price.value;
  const table = document.getElementById("results");
  const row = table.insertRow(-1);
  const cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  const cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  const cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  const cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  const cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
  const cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
  cell1.innerHTML = productID;
  cell2.innerHTML = product_desc;
  cell3.innerHTML = qty;
  cell4.innerHTML = price;
  cell5.innerHTML = ' <button type="button" onClick="editProduct(this);"/>Edit</button>';
  cell6.innerHTML = '<button type="button" onClick="deleteProduct(this);">Delete</button>';
}

function editProduct(node) {
  /*
  Get the <tr> that the clicked button (node) is within with .closest().
  Collect the all <td> of <tr> with .cells into an array with Array.from().
  */
  const cells = Array.from(node.closest("tr").cells);
  /*
  For the first 4 <td>s, toggle the ["contenteditable"] attribute.
  */
  cells.forEach((cell, index) => {
    if (index < 4) {
      cell.toggleAttribute("contenteditable");
    }
  });
}

function deleteProduct(node) {
  /*
  Find the <tr> that contains the clicked button and remove the <tr>
  */
  node.closest("tr").replaceChildren();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Shopping Cart Pure Javascript</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--
  ["required"] attribute only applies if <form> is being submitted.
  -->
  <form id="order">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="productID">Product ID:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="productID" name="product">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="product_desc">Product Desc:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="product_desc" name="product">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="quantity" name="quantity">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="price">Price:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="price" name="price">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="reset">
    <!-- 
    Change [type] to "reset" so the <form> will be cleared when 
    this button is clicked.
    -->
    <input onclick="addProduct();" type="reset" value="Add New Product">
  </form>
  <br>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" width="50">ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Product Description</th>
        <th scope="col" width="50">Quantity</th>
        <th scope="col" width="50">Price</th>
        <th scope="col" width="50">Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <!--
    Add <tbody> and assign #id to it instead of <table>.
    Otherwise each new <tr> will be inserted into <thead>
    -->
    <tbody id="results"></tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```